# What do you call a thing from YouTube in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I have seen words such as *filmo*, *filmeto*, *video*, *videaĵo*, but people tend to disagree about what is correct or not. Is there a general consensus between dictionaries about the definitions? Can you call all these units from YouTube with a unique term, or does it always depend on the kind of content (movie, music, infographics) presented?

Comment: I think it is more common to say filmeto or if it is a full length movie, then filmo.

Answer (score 10):

A ***filmo*** is a collection of images which can be shown (cf. the technically a bit outdated [definition by PIV](http://vortaro.net/#filmo)).

***video*** is the technical electronical managing of images (and sound), see [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#video).

So, the word you are searching is *filmo* (and *filmeto* when you mean a short movie). Usually you won't need the word *video* unless you're talking about technical stuff like editing a movie. The use of *video* in the meaning of *filmo* is probably motivated by similar words with a broader meaning in ethnic languages. The word *muzikvideo*, however, seems to b popular (at least it has got a Wikipedia article).

Of course, the word *videaĵo*, meaning "something produced by video" is OK, but it may put an accent on the technical side that most people probably don't feel.

Comment: The word "video" can be useful for the video that one can switch on when talking to someone on Skype. Other than that "filmeto" mostly works as a translation of the English "video". I use "filmo" almost exclusively for feature films, and "filmeto" for anything shorter than that (though I do say "desegnofilmo" without "-et-" for an animiated cartoons, even when they are not feature films).

Comment: I've sometimes seen "Jutubaĵo" for a YouTube video, but I don't have any official source for that word.

Answer (score 2):

I'll preface this by saying that I choose not to Esperantize brand names; I find it's much more practical from the reader's side to just see the word itself, with an Esperanto suffix if necessary (e.g. *Mi ŝatas YouTube-on*)

With that said, I'd simply suggest *YouTube-aĵoj*. If more precision were required, while still getting the "YouTube" point across, I'd say something like *YouTube-a video/filmo*.